# Can we use if statement with Etree Parsing

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am quite confused and want to ask about if statement used in a loop with `find()` method.

I wanted to insert these data into a database and each data have a unique value which will only can be identified by its result.

The results available are "Passed"//"Incomplete"//"Failed"//"Failed, Incomplete, Error"//

Here is an example of the file

```
<TestSuite>
       <TestCase>
          <TestResult>
            Failed
          </TestResult>
          <VerificationFailed>
            Not enough Fuel.
          </VerificationFailed>
       </TestCase>
    
       <TestCase>
          <TestResult>
            Passed
          </TestResult>
       </TestCase>
    
       <TestCase>
          <TestResult>
            Incomplete
          </TestResult>
          <TestDescription>
            Engine not set up properly.
          </TestDescription>
       </TestCase>
    
        <TestCase>
          <TestResult>
            Failed, Incomplete, Error
          </TestResult>
          <ExceptionThrown>
            Error, Capacity Overload.
          </ExceptionThrown>
        </TestCase>
</TestSuite>
```

I have tried using this code to get the values of these fields but it only returns "Passed"

```
tree = ET.parse('NewestReport.xml')
test = tree.findall('TestCase')
    for ts in test:
        result = ts.find('TestResult').text
        if result in "Failed":
            description = ts.find('VerificationFailed').text
            print(description)
        elif result in "Failed, Incomplete, Error":
            description = ts.find('ExceptionThrown').text
            print(description)
        elif result in "Incomplete":
            description = ts.find('TestDescription').text
            print(description)
        else:
            description = "Passed"
            print(description)
```

The expected output is 4 results of description that prints out the text from each unique fields (for "Failed" the text will be from `<VerificationFailed>` , for "Incomplete" the text will be from `<TestDescription>` , for "Failed, Incomplete, Error" the text will be from `<ExceptionThrown>` and finally for "Passed" it will be the string "Passed".

I have tried the code but it only gives out the value passed. I need it to be able to get different values.

Comment: Fix the XML and explain what is the expected output

Comment: XML file edited, and I also tried to explain the expected output as well as I can (sorry for my bad english) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below is what you are looking for

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<TestSuite>
       <TestCase>
          <TestResult>
            Failed
          </TestResult>
          <VerificationFailed>
            Not enough Fuel.
          </VerificationFailed>
       </TestCase>
    
       <TestCase>
          <TestResult>
            Passed
          </TestResult>
       </TestCase>
    
       <TestCase>
          <TestResult>
            Incomplete
          </TestResult>
          <TestDescription>
            Engine not set up properly.
          </TestDescription>
       </TestCase>
    
        <TestCase>
          <TestResult>
            Failed, Incomplete, Error
          </TestResult>
          <ExceptionThrown>
            Error, Capacity Overload.
          </ExceptionThrown>
        </TestCase>
</TestSuite>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for tc in root.findall('.//TestCase'):
  result = tc.find('TestResult').text.strip()
  if result == 'Failed':
    print(f'{result} : {tc.find("VerificationFailed").text.strip()}')
  elif result == 'Passed':
    print(result)
  elif result == 'Incomplete':
    print(f'{result} : {tc.find("TestDescription").text.strip()}')
  elif result == 'Failed, Incomplete, Error':
    print(f'{result} : {tc.find("ExceptionThrown").text.strip()}')
```

output

```
Failed : Not enough Fuel.
Passed
Incomplete : Engine not set up properly.
Failed, Incomplete, Error : Error, Capacity Overload.
```

Comment: You changed the XML. Part of the problem is that there is a lot of whitespace in the original XML.

Comment: @mzjn I have copied the xml into online xml formatter https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html and I worked on the result. I am not aware of any significant change that was done..

Comment: It is significant when doing `if result == 'Failed'`, for example. "Failed" is surrounded by whitespace in the XML in the question.

Comment: Got it. So `strip()` should care of it - isnt it?

Comment: @mzjn Code was modified in order to support the *original* xml

Comment: OK! IMHO, it is unnecessary to repeat the whole XML in the answer. Now you need to scroll to see the code.